# Unable to add typescript support in my quasar web application

Tags: javascript, typescript, quasar

I am trying to add typescript support on my quasar application. According to the quasar documentation I have set the configuration in tsconfig.json and quasar.config.js:

Following is the configuration in my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "extends": "@quasar/app-webpack/tsconfig-preset.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": ["esnext", "dom"],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~*": ["src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.d.ts", "src/**/*.tsx", "src/**/*.vue"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

And it is giving me the following errors:

1. Path to base configuration file to inherit from. Requires TypeScript version 2.1 or later.
2. File '@quasar/app-webpack/tsconfig-preset.json' not found

And below is my quasar.config.js:

```
module.export = function( /* ctx */ ) {
    return {
        supportTS: true,
        build: {
            rtl: true
        },
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `@quasar/app-webpack/tsconfig-preset.json` to `@quasar/app/tsconfig-preset.json`. Looks like the docs are either dated or don't cover all situations.

Comment: Didnot resolve the issue, in my case

Answer (score 0):

For a **Quasar 3 vite app**, this might help:
Change `@quasar/app-webpack/tsconfig-preset.json` to `@quasar/app-vite/tsconfig-preset.json`